# Getting error while installing the crossplane ProviderConfig in kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, crossplane

Getting error while installing the crossplane ProviderConfig in kubernetes cluster

```
root@kube-master:~/crossplane# kubectl apply -f ProviderConfig.yaml 
error: resource mapping not found for name: "default" namespace: "" from "ProviderConfig.yaml": no matches for kind "ProviderConfig" in version "aws.upbound.io/v1beta1"
ensure CRDs are installed first
```

ProviderConfig.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: aws.upbound.io/v1beta1
kind: ProviderConfig
metadata:
  name: default
spec:
  credentials:
    source: Secret
    secretRef:
      namespace: crossplane-system
      name: aws-secret
      key: creds
```

Did anyone face the same issue and got resolved?, please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the `ProviderConfig` you need to first install the `Provider`.

Based on the `apiVersion`, it looks like you are trying to install a config for [provider-aws](https://marketplace.upbound.io/providers/upbound/provider-aws/v0.37.0). You have a couple of options.

1. You can install providers from the AWS [provider family](https://docs.upbound.io/providers/provider-families/), which allows you to select which APIs you want to use. For example, S3 and EC2:

```bash
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: upbound-provider-aws-s3
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-s3:v0.37.0
---
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: upbound-provider-aws-ec2
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws-ec2:v0.37.0
EOF
```

2. You can install the monolithic provider (900+ CRDs in one provider)

```bash
kubectl apply -f - <<EOF
apiVersion: pkg.crossplane.io/v1
kind: Provider
metadata:
  name: provider-aws
spec:
  package: xpkg.upbound.io/upbound/provider-aws:v0.37.0
EOF
```